# How to replace text of current document URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Ex:

Following is my current document.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgxJHBJ_X-g&feature=related

I have a User Script and the code is

```
var doc = document.location.toString();
doc = doc.replace("v=cgxJHBJ_X-g","v=2AGrlGvtLxE");
```

I am just trying to replace the current document URL with some other URL. But I am getting the following Error.

Uncaught TypeError: Object http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgxJHBJ_X-g&feature=related has no method 'replace'

Comment: I see no reason why the code you posted wouldn't work, or at least not error.

Comment: But the code is not working and I am getting an error.

Comment: try window.location.href instead

Comment: I should have posted an answer then :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.URL` or `window.location.href` instead of `document.location.toString()`.

Example:

```
var url = document.URL;
window.location.href = url.replace("v=cgxJHBJ_X-g","v=2AGrlGvtLxE").
```

Comment: By using document.URL also, I am getting an error.

window.location.href is working fine

Comment: **@Rob**
unsafeWindow.document.URL is also working fine

thanks